# How to use custom NamespaceHandlerResolver when creating XML ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I would like to use a custom [`NamespaceHandlerResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerResolver.html) when creating a spring application context from xml.

The spring documentation only [explains](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#xml-custom) how to create custom [`NamespaceHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandler.html). But I need to use a specifically initialized `NamespaceHandlerResolver` in order to get the `NamespaceHandler`s I need to use corretly initialized (`NamespaceHandler`s are context dependent).

So when creating an xml applicationcontext, how to set a custom `NamespaceHandlerResolver`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs to create an application context derived from [`org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractXmlApplicationContext.html) and must override [`initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractXmlApplicationContext.html#initBeanDefinitionReader-org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader-). The override should set the custom `NamespaceHandlerResolver` to the `reader` instance.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerResolver;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class CustomNamespaceHandlerClassPathXmlApplicationContext extends ClassPathXmlApplicationContext {

    private NamespaceHandlerResolver customNamespaceHandlerResolver;

    @Override
    protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader) {
        super.initBeanDefinitionReader(reader);
        reader.setNamespaceHandlerResolver(customNamespaceHandlerResolver);
    }

    public void setCustomNamespaceHandlerResolver(
            NamespaceHandlerResolver customNamespaceHandlerResolver) {
        this.customNamespaceHandlerResolver = customNamespaceHandlerResolver;
    }
}
```