# OSGi/Equinox application launch fails due to "301 Moved Permanently" when resolving XSD

Tags: java, spring, xsd, osgi, equinox

We have an older (maintenance branch) version of a OSGi/Java application that relies on Spring 4.2.6.

Recently, when attempting to launch the application in a new developer workspace, the launch fails. **It seems** the root cause is that an XSD file has moved. Specifically, the HTTP request is redirected to HTTPS:

[image]

**Now, this isn't something I can control.** So I'd like to figure out:

1. Can I disable XSD validation/loading for my application, or
2. Do I need to upgrade to a newer version of Spring? I'd like to avoid this as it's a maintenance branch for which we're providing critical bug-only updates.

The stack:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.RemotePluginTestRunner.main(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.CoreTestApplication.run(CoreTestApplication.java:23)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.runApp(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 2 in XML document from OSGi resource[classpath:/test-spring-config.xml|bnd.id=11|bnd.sym=com.mycompany.myapplication] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 35; s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '301 Moved Permanently'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$301(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.normalRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$NoDependenciesWaitRefreshExecutor.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:157)
    at com.mycompany.myapplication.OsgiBundleXmlContextLoader.loadContext(OsgiBundleXmlContextLoader.java:26)
    at com.mycompany.myapplication.OsgiBundleXmlContextLoader.loadContext(OsgiBundleXmlContextLoader.java:32)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 35; s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '301 Moved Permanently'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.characters(SchemaDOMParser.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:630)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:686)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2181)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:578)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:610)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.processJAXPSchemaSource(XMLSchemaLoader.java:774)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:599)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2447)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1768)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:741)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 61 more
```

The stack refers to `line 2` of one of our XML configuration files, but it simply contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
                        http://www.springsecurity.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd">
...
```

Note that if I change line 2 to read:

```
<beans>
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Which OSGi framework and which container (Karaf?) are you using here? You might be running into https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=461046 which means it is actually not using the gemini core (which provides the XSD locally).

Comment: Sorry, we're using Equinox. Will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to replicate the issue and find a workaround for the 301 redirect on the DTD.

First, I've set up a test in which the AplicationContext is constructed based on an XML file with a 301 reference:

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

public class MovedDtdTest {

  @Test
  public void test()throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath:test.xml");
  }
}
```

test.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.nos.nl">
</beans>
```

Which resulted in the same exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
Line 2 in XML document from class path resource [test.xml] is invalid;
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://nos.nl/;
lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 35; s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters
are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'.
Saw '301 Moved Permanently'.
...
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
```

Then, I started debugging the stack trace and noticed that the following static attribute is present in the file `XmlBeanDefinitionReader`:

```java
public static final int VALIDATION_NONE = XmlValidationModeDetector.VALIDATION_NONE;
```

Which is set in `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader#setValidating`:

```java
public void setValidating(boolean validating) {
    this.validationMode = (validating ? VALIDATION_AUTO : VALIDATION_NONE);
    this.namespaceAware = !validating;
}
```

*Optionally, you could add a breakpoint in the method above and set `validating` to false in order to test it.*

After googling on how to override the `XmlBeanDefinitionReader`, I came across an old StackOverflow post on how to create and use a [custom NamespaceHandlerResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697960/how-to-use-custom-namespacehandlerresolver-when-creating-xml-applicationcontext)

I changed it to alter the behaviour of the XmlBeanDefinitionReader instead of the NamespaceHandlerResolver:

```java
public class CustomClassPathXmlApplicationContext extends FileSystemXmlApplicationContext {

  public CustomClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String... configLocations) throws BeansException {
    super(configLocations, true, null);
  }

  @Override
  protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader) {
    super.initBeanDefinitionReader(reader);
    reader.setValidating(false);
  }
}
```

And edited my test to load the ApplicationContext using the `CustomClassPathXmlApplicationContext`:

```java
  @Test
  public void test()throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext context = new CustomClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:test.xml");
  }
```

The test now passes with:

```
18:28:41.753 [main] DEBUG xxx.xx.xx.CustomClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing xx.xx.xx.x.CustomClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2bbf4b8b
18:28:42.014 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loaded 0 bean definitions from class path resource [test.xml]
```

I don't know how the ApplicationContext is loaded within your application, but  as you mentioned a 'legacy' application I used XmlConfig instead of JavaConfig.

I hope you'll be able to find some way to modify the behavior of the `XmlBeanDefinitionReader` in your ApplicationContext. It needs to happen in an early stage of the Spring lifecycle as the XML is parsed before the beans are created.

Comment: This worked! We already had a custom `*XmlApplicationContext` class, we just needed to override the `initBeanDefinitionReader()` method and add the `setValidating(false)` call. Hope this helps other folks as well. (Bounty can be awarded in 19 hours.)